# How to use ETDataExtension / ETResponse / ETConfiguration by Salesforce Marketing Cloud Java SDK

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, soap, java

I need to download more than 2500 Rows from tables of Salesforce Marketing Cloud with following code(for ETSubscriber):

```
ETConfiguration configuration = new ETConfiguration();
        configuration.set("clientId", clientId);
        configuration.set("clientSecret", clientSecret);
        configuration.set("authEndpoint", authEndpoint);
        configuration.set("endpoint", endpoint);
        configuration.set("soapEndpoint", soapEndpoint);
        configuration.set("useOAuth2Authentication", useOAuth2Authentication);

ETClient client = new ETClient(configuration);
       ETFilter etf = new ETFilter();
        etf.addProperty("id");
        etf.addProperty("key");
        etf.addProperty("createdDate");
        etf.addProperty("emailAddress");
        etf.addProperty("preferredEmailType");
        etf.addProperty("emailTypePreference");
        etf.addProperty("status");
        etf.addProperty("unsubscribedDate");

        ETResponse<ETSubscriber> response = client.retrieve(ETSubscriber.class, etf);

while (response.hasMoreResults()) {

// my Problem is here, I don't know how to start a next iteration?   

}
```

Comment: Have you reviewed this https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/continuerequest_2500records.htm

Comment: @EazyE thanks for link, yes saw that, but I don't understand, how can I do it in java